# guardar un json en una variable string desde un metodo post en c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Tengo una web api y estoy recibiendo en un método post un json, necesito en el método post almacenar todo el json en una variable string para luego guardarla en un campo de una tabla sql. No necesito deserializar el json, solo almacenarlo. Estoy usando c# vs2022.

Éste es el código que estoy usando, funciona pero solo me guarda los valores correspondientes al campo y no a la estructura.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] in_codes in_Codes)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ApiBBookContext dbContext = new ApiBBookContext())
            {
                //string json = in_Codes.json.ToString();
                dbContext.in_codes.Add(in_Codes);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, in_Codes);
                message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri +
                    in_Codes.id.ToString());
                return message;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
```

y este es un jason de prueba que estoy usando.

```
{
 "json": "prueba de json"
}
```

y lo que necesito es obtener esto:

```
string json = "{""json": "prueba de json"}"
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta, incluye lo que has intentado. Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Cambia Post([FromBody] in_codes in_Codes) por Post([FromBody] string in_Codes)

Comment: Con este cambio me sigue dando Null, pero cambie string por  Post([FromBody] object in_Codes)  y ahi si me resulto, gracias @Yussef